# NOT NULL constraint failed in go orm

Tags: go, orm

I'm trying to execute operation insert with orm in go.

I do insert and not assign value to time type value like the field:

```
ReplyTime       time.Time `orm:"index"`
```

it will throw error: `NOT NULL constraint failed: topic.reply_time`.

So how can I set this value to be nullable or a default value?

```
type Topic struct {
    Id              int64
    UId             int64
    Title           string
    Content         string `orm:"size(5000)"`
    Attachment      string
    Created         time.Time `orm:"index"`
    Updated         time.Time `orm:"index"`
    Views           int64 `orm:"index"`
    Author          string
    ReplyTime       time.Time `orm:"index"`
    ReplyCount      int64
    ReplyLastUserId int64
}

func AddTopic(title, content string) error {
    o := orm.NewOrm()
    t := time.Now()

    topic := &Topic{Title:title, Content:content, Created:t, Updated:t}
    _, err := o.Insert(topic)
    return err
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> So how can I set this value to be nullable or a default value?

You can either:

1. Remove the `not null` constraint from the database and change the type to something that accepts null values. Go includes a few of those in the standard library (e.g. [`sql.Null*`](https://golang.org/pkg/database/sql/)) but doesn't have one for `time.Time`. Write your own or use something like [`github.com/guregu/null`](https://github.com/guregu/null) which adds support for this.
2. Make sure you always set the `ReplyTime` field before inserting it in the database.

The "best" solution will depend on your application and what this data signifies. Should it be logically possible for `ReplyTime` to have "no value" (e.g. user never replied)? If so, then use option 1. If it should always have a value, then use option 2.

Comment: thanks for your help. I'm confused about the "time" type, does it support nullable or just because I add this "`orm:"index"`" to the value.